# Run python code oh button click without redirecting

Tags: python, ajax, django

I'm working on a web-page, which allows to move a camera. I created some buttons, so whenever you press it, we go to urls.py "moveRight" and then to the views.py. In a views.py move() function (which is a python script) moves a camera, and then I go back to the first page, where the button was.

panel.py

```
<form action="{% url 'cameracontrol:moveRight' %}" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <button type="submit" id="right" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Move right"></button>
</form>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.panelView, name='panel'),
    url(r'^right/$', views.moveCameraRight, name='moveRight'),
]
```

views.py

```
def moveCameraRight(request): # 
    move()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/cameracontrol/')
```

But I need the /cameracontrol/ page running without any reloading. I saw something about ajax, but couldn't figure out how exactly to use it here

Comment: Use ajax and in `views.py` just return `None`. it will not reload.

Comment: @vinaykumar - No, all views *must* return a response. Yes, you do need to use ajax, but a full explanation of how to use ajax is too broad

Comment: for response, you can use like this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects.
and for ajax you can use http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work.

## Ajax Call

```
$('#action-button').click(function() {
   $.ajax({
      url: 'http://api.joind.in/v2.1/talks/10889',
      success: function(data) {},
      type: 'GET'
   });
});
```

## views.py

```
def moveCameraRight(request): # 
    move()
    return JsonResponse({'move': 'right'})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html file you could add some JavaScript to make Ajax calls. I'm adding the JQuery library because it makes it easier to work with JavaScript

```
<!--somefile.html-->
<html>
<head>....</head>
<body>
    <button id="right" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Move right"></button>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#right').on('click', function() {
                $.ajax({% url 'cameracontrol:moveRight' %});
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is just a basic example. What the JQuery code is, "On click of element with ID='right' call the given function." And that function in turns calls your url.
In this example I've used GET instead of post as your code doesn't show any need to use post (except maybe only certain users can move the camera). To make it post you simple need to pass an object to the ajax call as such

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
});
```

But you also need to include the CSRF token in the header. I usually do the following

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
    if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", {% csrf_token %});
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this one, but when I click on the button it doesn't response, what should be in a views.py response?

Comment: In the code I've posted the response doesn't matter. I thought the purpose was only to move the camera, you can return any response and handle it on the success callback of ajax. Are you showing a preview of the camera? It it a single image or a streaming response? If it's streaming your ajax response doesn't matter

Comment: I mean after clicking nothing happens, I can't reach my move() script.
You wrote : 
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#right').on('click', function() {
                $.ajax({% url 'cameracontrol:moveRight' %});
            });
        });
What is document? Am I supposed to write something different?

Comment: Can you check if there are any errors in the debugging console of your browser. I might have missed something.   
And document is the html document. It's a special variable in JavaScript